# how to save this array in database using cake php

Tags: cakephp

```
[Ticket] => Array
    (
        [id] => Array
            (
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 6
            )

        [passenger_name] => Array
            (
                [1] => ticket
                [2] => ticket2
            )

        [age] => Array
            (
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 10
            )

        [gender] => Array
            (
                [1] => Female
                [2] => Male
            )

    )
```

this is my array output  and i want to save data on ticket table both entries

Comment: `$save=serialize($array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first construct the array as cake expects -

```
$tickets = array(
    'id' => array (
            1 => 5,
            2 => 6
        ),

    'passenger_name' => array
        (
            1 => 'ticket',
            2 => 'ticket2'
        ),

    'age' => array
        (
            1 => 2,
            2 => 10
        ),

    'gender' => array
        (
            1 => 'Female',
            2 => 'Male'
        )

);
foreach ($tickets as $key => $ticket) {
    foreach ($ticket as $newKey => $value) {
        $newTickets[$newKey]['Ticket'][$key] = $ticket[$newKey];
    }
}
```

then save the array - `$newTickets`